# CSS Formatting in a child component does not display proper format when called from Parent component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have child component which accepts few input parameters and displays the same as text information in box kind of format. The issue is when I call this child component from parent component using aura:iteration then the same box format is not retained. CSS styling is not retained in the child object because when input text is large then it extends. Please let me know how to make responsive design with input text and also the box format.

Child Component: SmallCompArticle

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
      <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" >
        <lightning:layoutItem size="10" padding="around-small">
          <div style="padding:15px;border-color:DarkGray;border-style: solid;height:230px;position:relative">
              <span style="font-size:14px;background-color:DarkGray;color:white;padding:5px">{!v.ChildType}</span>

              <br/>
                <p style="font-size:150%;">{!v.ChildTitle} </p>
              <br/>
                <p style="font-size:125%;">{!v.ChildDesc}</p>

                <!--<p align="right" style="font-size:250%;">&rarr;</p> -->
              <div  style="font-size:250%;vertical-align:bottom;line-height:normal;display: inline-block;height: 40px;
                    width: 40px;
                    background-color: #999999;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    right: 0px;">&rarr;
              </div>
          </div>                            
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>  
</aura:component>
```

Parent Calling component:

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.articleList}" var="row">
      <c:SmallCompArticle ChildType="{!row.Type__c}" ChildTitle="{!row.Title}" ChildDesc="{!row.Description__c}"/>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:layout>
```